# Best way to inherit methods from a parent class to multiple subclasses in django

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have multiple subclasses that uses very similar methods with differing arguments I want to pass. For instance I'm using the parent subclass  SportsSentiment that contains a function that returns all the rows for an individual league (NBA, NFL, MLB...etc).

Here is the Parent Class:

```
from django.db import models
from sports_sentiment.main.models import SentimentPoint

class SportsSentimentMixin(models.Model):
    test = "abc"

    # I want my subclasses to inherit this method!
    def get_league_sentimental_points(self, league):
        return SentimentPoint.objects.all().filter(league=league)


    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

An example of a subclass:

```
from sports_sentiment.custom_mixins import SportsSentimentMixin

class NBASportsSentimentView(TemplateView, SportsSentimentMixin):
    template_name = 'NBA/sports_sentiment.html'

    # This doesn't work, but I'm trying to get the the 
    # the function get_league_sentimental_points from the parent
    # class
    nba_data = self.get_league_sentimental_points("NBA")
```

Comment: It's... very unusual to subclass both `models.Model` and a class-based view. Anyway, you're trying to call an instance method in the context of a class. At that point there is no instance, so you can't call a method on `self`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going at it kind of backwards. First, your mixin does not need to be a model. Why not just make it a base view that queries for the sentiment points based on the league. Then you can just inherit from that view and override the `template_name` and `league`!

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from sports_sentiment.main.models import SentimentPoint


class SportsSentimentView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'ABC/sports_sentiment.html'
    league = 'ABC'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # This method builds a dictionary of variables that will be passed
        # to the template for rendering
        context = super(SportsSentimentView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['points'] = SentimentPoint.objects.filter(league=self.league)
        return context


class NBASportsSentimentView(SportsSentimentView):
    template_name = 'NBA/sports_sentiment.html'
    league = 'NBA'

# Adding more leagues is now super simple!
class NHLSportsSentimentView(SportsSentimentView):
    template_name = 'NHL/sports_sentiment.html'
    league = 'NHL'
```